# default: "now()" in Sequel generates literal embedded into the defenitiion of a table

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm trying to create a default value in Sequel:

```
create_table(:my_table) do
  primary_key :id
  # ..........
  Timestamp :created_at, default: "now()"
```

After running a migration, it generates a table with this column definition:

```
  --........
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT '2017-10-28 12:26:00.129157'::timestamp without time zone,
```

But what I want is the value "now()" to be set when I'm inserting a new value.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a while ago but I had a similar problem that I solved by using `Sequal.lit`

`Timestamp :created_at, default: Sequel.lit("now()")`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set a String in a Time field? I don't think this is going to work. You'll have to use `String :created_at, default: "now()"`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is as follows, using either `Sequel.function(:now)` or `Sequel::CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```rb
Time :created_at, default: Sequel.function(:now)
# or...
Time :created_at, default: Sequel::CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```